# Nomenclature with Complex Substituents

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

[image]

For the above molecule, I know that the longest carbon chain has 7 carbons, so the backbone is heptane.

The two substituents are at the 4 position on the heptane.

One of the substituents is a methyl group. That much is obvious.

The other appears to be a complex substituent and is a 1-chloroethyl group.

Thus, would the name be:

4,4-(1-chloroethyl)methylheptane?

I think the issue is what happens when we have *different* substituents with the same loctant. I've looked in one book and at all its practice problems, and this scenario *never* occurs.

I know that 4-methylheptane is a real compound and that its name is *correct*. So I am leaning toward 4,4-(1-chloroethyl)methylheptane as being a correct name; the complex substituent is correctly named; both locatants are present; everything is alphabetized; my only issue is whether I am missing some convention (e.g. should there be a dash somewhere, a comma somewhere, or what?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Close. But each (different type of) group added to the heptane backbone is numbered separately: 4-(1-chloroethyl)-4-methylheptane. Also, you have an asymmetric carbon, so the chirality needs to be specified (I will leave that to you).

Comment: Actually we are both wrong. The longest, most substituted chain in this compound is the 6-carbon chain (hexane).

Comment: This 6 carbon chain as a 2-chloro substituent, a 3 methyl substituent, and a 3 propyl substituent; therefore the name is (2S)-chloro-3-methyl-3-propylhexane.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure anymore about the above name (the one my professor gave). I just read in Wade that we use the longest chain; if there are two chains of equal length, use the one that is more substituted. The longest chain is unequivocally the 7-carbon chain.

Comment: @Dissenter I believe this answer is as correct as it gets. And your last comment also substantiates this claim. Maybe it is time to accept this answer ;D (And you could clear some of your comments)